# $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroup of $G$ such that $H\cap K=e$, $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find proof of isomorphism between internal direct product and external direct product of a group.
i had a mapping  $\varphi(hk)=(h,k)$.
To prove preserving structure for an isomorphism, i need the proof.
I know that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$,
$HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$.
Please help.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ and $G=HK$ the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$. Define $\phi: H \times K \to G$, $\phi: (h,k) \mapsto hk$.Let's show that it is an isomorphism:

$\phi((h,k) \cdot (h_1,k_1)) = \phi(hh_1,kk_1) = hh_1kk_1$
but the elements of $H,K$ commutes so: $\phi((h,k) \cdot (h_1,k_1)) = hh_1kk_1=hkh_1k_1 = \phi(h,k)\phi(h_1,k_1)$ so $\phi$ is a morphism.

Now let's prove that's injective, $\phi(h,k)=e_G \Rightarrow hk=e_G \Rightarrow h=k=e_G$ (where $e_G$ is the identity of $G$) so $\ker \phi=\{(e_G,e_G)\}=\{e_{H \times K}\}$ and this implies that $\phi$ is injective.

Since $G$ is the internal direct product $HK$ every element of $G$ can be writen in the form $hk$ where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ and then $\phi$ is surjective. This proves that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and then the internal and external direct products are isomorphs.

Comment: You are using $G$ for two different things. Either you should give $HK$ a different name, or you should say why there is no loss of generality in assuming that $G=HK$.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to approach this which does not assume that $hk=kh$ for all $h \in H, k \in K$. Replacing $G$ with $HK$ for convenience, note that we have quotient maps $q_1\colon G \to G/K$ and $q_2\colon G \to G/H$. Since $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$, the map $q_1$ restricts to an isomorphism $q_H\colon H \to G/K$, and similarly $q_2$ restricts to an isomorphism $q_K \colon K \to G/H$.

But then the map $f\colon G \to H\times K$ given by $f(x) = (q_H^{-1}q_1(x),q_K^{-1}q_2(x))$ is a homomorphism of groups, and if $f(x) = (e_H,e_K)$ then $x \in \ker(q_1)\cap \ker(q_2)= K\cap H = \{e\}$, so that $f$ is injective. Moreover, $f(H)=H\times \{e_K\}$ and $f(K) = \{e_H\}\times K$ and clearly $H\times \{e_K\} \cup \{e_H\}\times K$ generate $H\times K$, so that $f$ is also surjective. But then $f$ is an isomorphism and $G = HK \cong H \times K$ as required.

[*Aside: If you know the Jordan-Holder theorem, then it is worth noting that this argument gives a strong version of the Jordan-Holder theorem for groups with a composition series of length $2$. Suppose that $G$ is a group with a composition series $\mathcal C = (0\lhd K\lhd G)$ of length $2$. Either $\mathcal C$ is the unique composition series for $G$, or $G\cong K\times G/K$ (and $G$ has more than $1$ composition series).*

*Indeed if $G$ has exactly one composition series there is nothing to prove, so we may suppose that $\mathcal C' = (0<H_k\lhd H_{k-1} \lhd \ldots \lhd H_1=H\lhd G)$ is another composition series with $\mathcal C' \neq \mathcal C$. Then $K$ and $H$ are normal subgroups, and $K$ and $G/K$ are simple groups. Since $K$ is simple, if $H=K$, then $\mathcal C' = \mathcal  C$, hence $H\neq K$. But then $KH$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ properly containing $K$, hence as $G/H$ is simple, $KH=G$. Similarly $K\cap H =\{e\}$ since it is a proper normal subgroup of the simple group $K$, and thus we may apply the result above to conclude that $G \cong K\times H$.*

*Note that both possibilities really do happen, as one already sees by considering the groups $C_4$ and $C_6 = C_2\times C_3$. (The example $C_3\times C_3$ is also worth thinking about.)*]